# VLC python binding issue => NameError: name 'u' is not defined

Tags: python, vlc

I add the vlc.py to my vlc install directory and then try running a basic example:

```
from vlc import *   
i=vlc.Instance('--no-audio', '--fullscreen')   
i.audio_get_volume()   
p=i.media_player_new()   
m=i.media_new('file:///tmp/foo.avi')   
m.get_mrl()    
p.set_media(m)
p.play()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vanilla\My Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\VoDSandbox\src\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from vlc import *
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.py", line 102, in <module>
    del p, u
NameError: name 'u' is not defined
```

There error happens during import. Obviously it finds the file, but parsing it is a problem for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They herped the derp. There is no `u`. Change the line to `del p` and log a bug.